# Почему нельзя запустить android приложение на Linux?

Tags: java, android, linux

Здравствуйте! Почти все приложения для Android написаны на Java. И тем не менее их нельзя запустить на компьютере. Почему? А если перекомпилировать?
В чем разница между Java на Android и Linux? Можно их запустить на компьютере?

Comment: Если их "перекомпилировать" особым образом, я думаю что вполне возможно.     
Есть ли такие "перекомпиляторы"? - уверен, что нету.    
Почему нету? - потому, что в этом абсолютно отсутствует смысл - Приложение на просто джаве (без Android SDK) написать проще, поэтому нет смысла писать более сложное приложение, что бы его потом "перекомпилировать" в более простое.     
А если уж сильно нужно - берете эмулятор, и запускаете... в чем проблема?

Comment: а разве все, что написано на Java, обязано запускаться на ПК?

Comment: Наверняка, я знаю можно через chrome запустить с помощью  [этого](https://github.com/vladikoff/chromeos-apk). Но это не совсем то)

Comment: Вот на днях была статейка на Хабре на эту тему: http://habrahabr.ru/post/253238/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во первых Андроид это операционная система и работает на виртуальной машине по жавой. Хоть и сделана на база линукса они разные, разные библеотеки, дрова и тд. Тем более приложение компилируется на архитектуру процессоров ARM. Но запустить на компе возможно с помощью эмулятора, па пример [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download).

Comment: Есть еще планшеты (да и телефоны вроде) на процессорах Intel (у меня такой ASUS), т.е. с архитектурой x86. Не пытался, а вот интересно, как же в случае с ними, можно запустить?

Comment: Да, можно уже компилировать на х86 но опять же, без операционной системы Android приложение не запустить. Можно устатновить Android на девайс с Intel Atom и только уже тогда запускать приложение. Это тоже самое что пробовать запустить приложение с IOS на Windows,ничего не получится.

Comment: Ерунду говорите про x86, пишу с асус 5,  никто спецом ничего не компилит, иногда бывает, что части библиотек не поддерживают, по факту столкнулся с тем что гуглокамера не умеет сферу

Comment: Ну да, без собственно java-машины Android (Dalvik) байткод не запустить в любом случае. Это уже собственно java-машина, как прослойка, под x86 скомпилирована.

Answer (score 14):

- Десктопная Java работает на Sun'овской виртуальной машине JVM
- Android'ная Java работает на виртуальной машине [Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)), которая по байткоду несовместима с JVM
- Начиная с Kitkat Android начал переход на новую виртуальную машину ART (Android Runtime)

Существуют перекомпиляторы с байткода JVM на Dalvik и обратно. Стандартно это делается с помощью утилиты `dx` встроенной в Android SDK. Но проблема в том, что это не поможет, поскольку Java байткод будет вызывать встроенные нативные функции телефона отсутствующие в десктопе.

Единственный выход - это запускать APK файлы в окружении эмулятора: либо на GenyMotion, который работает поверх Ораклевской виртуалки, либо стандартного AVD устройства идущего в комплекте с Android SDK.

**Update**

Сообщается, что выпущен плагин для браузера Chrome, который позволяет запускать Андроид приложение в окружении браузера: [втыкаем и читаем](http://open.cnews.ru/top/2015/04/02/androidprilozheniya_stalo_vozmozhno_zapuskat_v_windows_mac_linux_i_chrome_os_instrukciya_594531)

Answer (score 3):

[ARC Welder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn) пытается решить проблему запуска Android-приложений на десктопе. Пока, похоже, не слишком удачно.

Comment: ARC роботает очень даже не плохо! Рекомендую!

Comment: Да, вполне хорошее начало.